# Insert a manual paragraph in an header of an R markdown beamer presentation

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown, knitr

I am doing a beamer presentation with R Markdown. I want to insert a manual paragraph in some of the headers. This is my code so far:

```
---
title: "An Introduction to Statistical Analysis with R"
author: Me
date: "15th of October 2019"
output: 
  beamer_presentation:
    slide_level: 2
---

# This is my first header
```

In the Beamer PDF File, I would like the header to be in two seperate paragraphs like this:

```
This is my
first header
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the LaTeX `\newline` command:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "10/23/2019"
output: beamer_presentation
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

## Multiline \newline Heading

blah blah blah
````

[image]

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to put 2 spaces after my, i.e.

This is my[space][space]

first header

Try that.

Comment: This is not working for me. If I do two spaces after my the output does not change and if I do two spaces and start a new line 'first header' is not part of the header anymore.